# Adding margin automatically on scroll down a page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In my wordpress site due to adding a plugin when I scroll down a page a top margin of 1068px is adding automatically. I could not find the code which is causing this problem. The page with the problem is http://geek-prime.com/the-death-of-wolverine-wolverine-3-months-to-die/

When you scroll down the header goes down 1068px. Let me know how to fix this. I added this code to make the top margin 0px but this is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript>

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#cb-container").css("margin-top: 0px");   
    });

</script>
```

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: I just checked page, and didn't see any issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the correct syntax for `.css()` by using:

```
$("#cb-container").css("margin-top","0px");
```

or:

```
$("#cb-container").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
```

instead of:

```
$("#cb-container").css("margin-top: 0px");
```

---

You also need to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#cb-container").css("margin-top","0px");
    });
});
```

Comment: You also need to wrap your code inside DOM ready hanlder. Please try my updated code.